# Haskell: difference in performance from different function composition?

Tags: performance, haskell, function-composition

The following code:

```
import Control.Exception
import Data.List

updateAverage :: (Fractional t) => (t, t) -> t -> (t, t)
updateAverage (old_value, old_counter) x =
    let new_counter = old_counter + 1
    in 
        assert(new_counter /= 0)
        old_value `seq` (old_value + (x - old_value) / new_counter, new_counter)

average values = fst (foldl' updateAverage (0.0, 0.0) values) -- version I

main = do
    let v = [1 .. 1000000]
    let a = average v
    putStrLn (show a)
```

becomes faster (compilation options: `ghc.exe -O3`) when I replace the definition of `average` function with

```
average = fst . foldl' updateAverage (0.0, 0.0) -- version II
```

What could be the reason for this? I thought that the differences between these two lines are basically syntax. Is the second version (without free variable `values`) easier for the compiler to optimize?

Funnily enough, when compiled without optimization, version I becomes faster.

**Timing results:**

options: `-O3`

version I: 0.280s
version II: 0.212s

options: (no optimization)

version I: 0.42s
version II: 0.44s

Measured using `time` shell command in Cygwin.

**Timing results with type=Double:**

Double:

options: -O3

version I: 0.22s
version II:: 0.212s

options: (no optimization)

version I: 0.34s
version II: 0.35s

*More info: I'm using the compiler*

```
> $ ghc -v Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.0.4, for Haskell 98,
> stage 2 booted by GHC version 6.12.2 Using binary package database:
> C:\Program Files\Haskell
> Platform\2011.4.0.0\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache wired-in package
> ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.2.0.0-e1f7c380581d61d42b0360d440cc35ed
> wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to
> integer-gmp-0.2.0.3-91607778cf3ae8f3948a50062b4f8479 wired-in package
> base mapped to base-4.3.1.0-f520cd232cc386346843c4a12b63f44b wired-in
> package rts mapped to builtin_rts wired-in package template-haskell
> mapped to template-haskell-2.5.0.0-7d9b1443ac5ab69e5ed705a487990deb
> wired-in package dph-seq not found. wired-in package dph-par not
> found. Hsc static flags: -static
> *** Deleting temp files: Deleting:
> *** Deleting temp dirs: Deleting: ghc.exe: no input files Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
under Cygwin.*
```

Comment: I would appreciate if the downvoters added comments explaining what they didn't like in the question.

Comment: +1 to restore the balance of the force

Comment: Could you show the difference in speed between the two versions and various levels of O, though? How did you measure it?

Comment: "becomes faster (compilation options: ghc.exe -O3) when I replace the definition of average function with" and "Funnily enough, when compiled without optimization, version II becomes faster." don't make sense together.

Comment: @Tsabo See the timing results. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Try giving `average` and `updateAverage` concrete floating types - i.e. use Double. Then see if there is a difference...

Comment: Added. The un-optimized version became faster, but the optimized version changed little.

Comment: @stephentetley Sorry -- both optimized and unoptimized builds of Version I code became faster.

Comment: Is 0.212s really correct for -O3 with version II and Dobule? It seems weird that execution time goes up 10x when using optimisation.

Comment: @danr ? all times are of the order of 1E-1 second.

Comment: @quant_dev Oh, silly me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. With ghc-7.0.4, version I is a wee bit faster (~1.5%) when compiling with optimisations (note: there is no -O3, if you give a level above 2, it is interpreted as 2). No difference whatsoever with 7.4.1. The (7.0.4) core for both versions is almost identical, the only difference is that version II uses `D# 0.0` for the initial values while version I uses `$wfromRat (S# 0) (S#1)`. If anything, I would expect the latter to be slower (perhaps a few hundred nanoseconds). I'm on 64 bits, that might make a difference. Will boot into 32 bits later to see.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why would you expect version II to be slower?

Comment: I wouldn't. Since the only difference in the core is the double literal versus the conversion `$wfromRat`, if anything, I would expect the conversion to be slower, that was version I. But since it's used only once, for the initial values of the fold, the difference should be at most the time for one conversion, a few dozen, perhaps hundred nanoseconds, not reliably measurable by `time`. However, here on my box, version I was slightly faster than version II when compiled by 7.0.4.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment.

Comment: Hmm, I can sort-of reproduce it with ghc-7.2.2 on 64 bits. On 32 bits, I got the same behaviour as on 64 with 7.0.4, with 7.2.2 it looks as if version II is a bit faster (not stable enough to be sure, maybe 1-1.5%), but with 7.2.2 on 64 bits (with -O2), version I is about 10% slower than version II. The generated core is basically the same as that of 7.0.4, the only difference between version I and II is again the `D# 0.0` vs the `fromRational` worker. Very strange, I have no idea how that comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I conjecture that something might be going on with stream fusion or loop fusion.  Perhaps there is a rewrite rule buried deep in the Prelude that is firing in one case or not in the other.  Or, because you don't say *how much* faster, you could simply be seeing cache effects.

If you want to know more, learn to fish:

- Use `ghc -ddump-simpl` to see the code that's actually being generated and compare it.
- Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to count the number of instructions being executed.

If nothing else, these tools will give you enough information that you can ask a more focused, detailed question.

Comment: Thanks! Version II does less type conversions. Is the morale that point-free syntax makes it easier for Haskell to optimize how it converts values between types?

Comment: @quant_dev It might be possible so.